# php concating variable and accessing array

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.6

is somthing like that possible?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
        $var = "bild" . $i;
        if (!empty ($row->bild.$i)) {
            echo '
                <div class="item">
                        <img border="no" class="bildschatten" src="include/images/projekte/'.$row->bild . $i.'" />
                </div>
            ';
        }
    }
```

how should it look correctly? problem is:

I fetch objects from a mysql database, in this table each object has 15 images

bild1 .. bild15

Now I want to iterate over this 15 images and want to check if the colum is empty or not.

the problem I have is here:

```
$row->bild.$i
```

that contains not the value of column bild1.. bild15 ... it only contains the value of $i

thanks

Comment: try `$row->$var`. for more details check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: mysterious tried this bevore ... its working now sorry for this stupid question

Comment: @Felix consider to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
$row->{'bild'.$i}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch the result as  an array uning

```
    $row  =  db_fetch_array($result)
```

and then  accessing

```
    $var = "bild" . $i;
    if (!empty ($row[$var])) {
```

Comment: then I got this: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in`
the row var is this: `while ($row = db_fetch_object($sql)) {`

Comment: @Felix   . like indicated at the beginning of the answer you shuold use  fetch the result as array   using  db_fetch_array($result)

Answer (score 1):

This is called variable of variables, You need to access something like this `$row->$var`.

**Complete Solution:**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    $var = "bild" . $i;
    if (!empty ($row->$var)) {
        echo '
            <div class="item">
                    <img border="no" class="bildschatten" src="include/images/projekte/'.$row->$var.'" />
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

For more details checkout the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).